# How to increase jvm heap size of a docker service?

Tags: docker, jvm, docker-swarm, heap-memory

We are using docker swarm on the server for orchestration. using openjdk8. My backend application is a rest service named "api". On the master, if do :

```
docker service ls
```

**see the result :**

```
ID                  NAME                               MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                                                PORTS
7l89205dje61        integration_api                    replicated          1/1                 docker.repo1.tomba.com/koppu/koppu-api:3.1.2.96019dc
.................
```

Time to time I am seeing an error in this docker service log (docker service logs integration_api):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

**And hence, I am trying to update jvm heap size for this docker service. so I tried :**

```
docker service update --env-add JAVA_OPTS="-Xms3G -Xmx3G -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" integration_api
```

**Saw this result:**

```
integration_api
overall progress: 1 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: running   [==================================================>]
```

However, it does not actually seem to increase the heap in the container. What should I do differently?

Comment: "*However, it does not actually seem to increase the heap in the container*" - How did you determine this?

Comment: I got inside the container : docker exec -it 66a202b11fa6 bash, then : java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -Ei "maxheapsize|maxram

Comment: That command launches a second JVM in the same container; it doesn't say anything about the memory configuration of the main container process.